# Why do I get a "Internal Error" when doing a BigQuery Extract

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using bq command line to extract a table to GCS.

```
bq --project_id=<project-id> extract -F "\t" mydataset.mytable gs://mybucket
```

I am getting error:

> 'An internal error has occurred'

This is a cron job and was working fine till 11th August. But it started failing from 12th-August.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Google Support said that the code responsible for conversion to CSV is hitting exception due to a bug and suggested to export the data to another format (AVRO or JSON).

Comment: Regarding internal errors in BigQuery, the best thing to do is to open a support case or a bug using the BigQuery issue tracker as mentioned in this document: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#internalError

Comment: Please check the scheme of the files that you are trying to load from GCS bucket to the table. The schema should be same across all files that you are loading. Most probably the schema changes will cause internal error issue.